# Contracted product of torsors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, group-actions, principal-bundles, torsors

Given a group $G$ and a left $G$-set $X$, then we can make $X$ a right $G$-set defining the action as $xg:=g^{-1}x$ , or if you prefer we are considering the [opposite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group) $G^{op}$ to make the left action a right action.

Now, talking about $G$-torsors, there is the notion of contracted product, i.e. a product of torsors. In the literature the definition of the product is:

*Given X a $(G,H)$-bitorsor and $Y$ a $(H,G)$-bitorsor then $X \times^H Y=\frac{X \times Y}{\Delta(H)}$ is a $G$-bitorsor*

Here $\Delta(H)$ is the diagonal action, or equivalently the equivalence relation is defined by $(xh,y) \sim (x,hy)$. One can show that this product is associative.

Now, my question is, here there is a definition based on bitorsors, but what if, given $X,Y$ left $G$-torsor, i take the quotient of the fibre product of $X,Y$ by the equivalence relation $(gx,y) \sim (x,gy)$? Why this is not a left $G$-torsor?

In the case where $G$ is abelian, we can note that every $G$-torsor is a $G$-bitorsor and the product will be a $G$-bitorsor as well. But in the non abelian case? I suppose that there could be a problem of associativity with this product, but I don't know if it is the case and why.

Comment: How would you define such a left $G$-action in the case that both $X$ and $Y$ are left $G$-torsors? The $G$-action in not constant on the equivalence classes if $G$ is not abelian.

Comment: The action would be $g(x,y)=(gx,y)$ Why this is not constant on the equivalence classes?

Comment: In your first paragraph, the left and right $G$ actions don't commute (unless $G$ is abelian).

Comment: Yes, this is true, I have edited the question.

Comment: Ok, rather the action is not free. Let $X=Y=G$. Then for $g,h\in G$, with your definition we have $(gh,1)\sim(h,g)\sim(1,hg)\sim(hg,1)$. Thus $(gh)^{-1}\cdot(gh,1)\stackrel{def}{=}((gh)^{-1}gh,1)=(1,1)$. But then $(hg)^{-1}\cdot(gh,1)\sim(hg)^{-1}\cdot(hg,1)\stackrel{def}{=}((hg)^{-1}hg,1)=(1,1)$. Thus $(gh)^{-1}\cdot(gh,1)= (hg)^{-1}\cdot(gh,1)=(1,1)$ so the action is not free unless $gh=hg, \forall g,h\in G$. That is $G$ is abelian.